# Default App chooser with "always" option

Tags: android, default

In one of my apps I want to ask a user to choose a web browser, and want the options "Once" and "Always" be available to them.

Right now I am using:

```
 Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 webIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
 webIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("android","com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity"));
 startActivity(webIntent);
```

And get the following result:

[image]

While this allows to choose the app and has options I need, to set Chrome as a default, the user will first have to click on Chrome, and then get this dialog again to set Chrome as a default (it will appear in place of Firefox).

But what I want to achieve is:

[image]

I tried different approaches I could find on SO with no luck.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This is a system behaviour, you cannot override this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mimmo noted, you cannot change the behavior of the system chooser, and the stock Android 5.0+ chooser only allows the user to make the last-visited app the default via "Always". Also, you have no way of setting the default app yourself, for obvious security reasons.

I also strongly recommend you get rid of your `setComponent()` call, as that is unlikely to work across all Android devices. Device manufacturers can and do change things like the chooser, which may well involve different classes in different packages.